# How do highlight/change color to div upon scrolling

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have 4 month milestone in my html. I would like to highlight the respective month when the scroll screen reaches the div.

Can you please help me with the javascript or query on how should I do that?

```
.highlight{
 color:blue;
}
```

HTML

```
<body> 
<div id="Jan" style="margin-bottom:50em;">  
   <p> January updates</p>
   blah blah blah 
</div>

<div id="Feb" style="margin-bottom:50em;"> 
   <p> February updates</p>
    blah blah blah 
</div>

<div id="Mar" style="margin-bottom:100em;"> 
   <p> March updates</p>
   blah blah blah 
</div>

<div id="Apr" > 
  <p> April updates</p>
  blah blah blah 
</div>
</body>
```

Here's the javascript I am trying to highlight div upon scroll.

```
<script>
var myDiv = document.getElementById("myBtn");

$(document).on('scroll', function() {
if($(this).scrollTop()>=$('#theTarget').position().top){
   if((myDiv)== "Jan" | "Feb" | "Mar" | "Apr" )
   {
         myDiv.setAttribute("class","highlight");
   }
  }
})
</script>
```

Comment: https://medium.com/talk-like/detecting-if-an-element-is-in-the-viewport-jquery-a6a4405a3ea2

Comment: It doesn't work. I keep getting error on my browser - Uncaught reference error $ not defined. Can you please help fix my code?

Answer (score 0):

You can see the following links

[css-tricks.com](https://css-tricks.com/slide-in-as-you-scroll-down-boxes/)

With the help of this example, you can apply your CSS for highlighting the div when div comes in visible area of computer